# aligning two mdframes extended over pages side by side

Tags: mdframed

I want to align two mdframes extended over multiple pages side by side.  Following is my code. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{11}{15}\selectfont}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
%\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{lipsum, showframe}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

%\definecolor{Brown}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.9}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
%\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\def\labelaxes{Remember to include your label}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=3cm, linecolor=red]

\raggedleft\textit{(15)\break
                        In preparation\break
                         \vspace{2pt}\break
                          (14)\break
                          In preparation\break
                          \vspace{0pt}\break
                          (13)\break
                          In preparation\break  
                         \vspace{12pt}\break
                          (12)\break
                          In preparation\break
                        \vspace{13pt}\break                         
                          (11)\break
                        In preparation\break
                        \vspace{13pt}\break  
                          (10)\break
                          In preparation\break
                          \vspace{2pt}\break  
                          (9)\break
                          In preparation\break
                        \vspace{-.5pt}\break                            
                          (8)\break
                          In preparation\break
                          \vspace{13pt}\break     
                          (7)\break
                          In preparation\break 
                           \vspace{28pt}\break     
                          (6)\break
                          In preparation\break 
                          \vspace{25pt}\break     
                          (5)\break
                          In preparation\break 
                          \vspace{30pt}\break     
                          (4)\break
                          In preparation\break 
                          \vspace{12pt}\break     
                          (3)\break
                          In preparation\break   
                           (2)\break
                        In preparation\break
                         \vspace{27pt}\break
                          (1)\break
                          In preparation\break }

\end{mdframed}


\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=11cm, linecolor=red]

 \raggedleft\textit{(15)\break
                        In preparation\break
                         \vspace{2pt}\break
                          (14)\break
                          In preparation\break
                          \vspace{0pt}\break
                          (13)\break
                          In preparation\break  
                         \vspace{12pt}\break
                          (12)\break
                          In preparation\break
                        \vspace{13pt}\break                         
                          (11)\break
                        In preparation\break
                        \vspace{13pt}\break  
                          (10)\break
                          In preparation\break
                          \vspace{2pt}\break  
                          (9)\break
                          In preparation\break
                        \vspace{-.5pt}\break                            
                          (8)\break
                          In preparation\break
                          \vspace{13pt}\break     
                          (7)\break
                          In preparation\break 
                           \vspace{28pt}\break     
                          (6)\break
                          In preparation\break 
                          \vspace{25pt}\break     
                          (5)\break
                          In preparation\break 
                          \vspace{30pt}\break     
                          (4)\break
                          In preparation\break 
                          \vspace{12pt}\break     
                          (3)\break
                          In preparation\break   
                           (2)\break
                        In preparation\break
                         \vspace{27pt}\break
                          (1)\break
                          In preparation\break }


\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try with `paracol` package.

Comment: While using paracol, I saw that every paragraph starts with an indent. Is there option to avoid that? Right now I am using \noindent at the beginning of the each para.

Comment: you can define newenvironment `myparacol` based on paracol and start with `\noindent\ignorespaces`

Comment: I am trying the \AtBeginEnvironment{paracol}{\noindent\ignorespaces}, however, I could not make it work and showing errors.  Please suggest.

Comment: If you start a new question I will answer it. Don't delete this one please.

Comment: I asked the question. Please answer.    http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296069/remove-indent-globally-from-the-paracol-paragraph