# remove indent globally from the \paracol paragraph

Tags: paracol

I am using \paracol for aligning the column across the pages.  However, on the right-hand side, there is always some indent before starting of every paragraph.  Please help me to avoid that?  Following is my code:

```
{\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{10}{18}\selectfont}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\AtBeginEnvironment{paracol}{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{lipsum, showframe}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

%\definecolor{Brown}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.9}

%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

%\definecolor{Brown}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.9}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
%\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\def\labelaxes{Remember to include your label}
 \usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}



 \begin{document}

 \columnratio{.3}
 \begin{paracol}{2}
 \begin{leftcolumn}
 \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=3cm, linecolor=red]

 \raggedleft\textit{(15)\break
                    In preparation\break
                     \vspace{2pt}\break
                      (14)\break
                      In preparation\break
                      \vspace{0pt}\break
                      (13)\break
                      In preparation\break  
                     \vspace{12pt}\break
                      (12)\break
                      In preparation\break
                    \vspace{13pt}\break                         
                      (11)\break
                    In preparation\break
                    \vspace{13pt}\break  
                      (10)\break
                      In preparation\break
                      \vspace{2pt}\break  
                      (9)\break
                      In preparation\break
                    \vspace{-.5pt}\break                            
                      (8)\break
                      In preparation\break
                      \vspace{13pt}\break     
                      (7)\break
                      In preparation\break 
                       \vspace{28pt}\break     
                      (6)\break
                      In preparation\break 
                      \vspace{25pt}\break     
                      (5)\break
                      In preparation\break 
                      \vspace{30pt}\break     
                      (4)\break
                      In preparation\break 
                      \vspace{12pt}\break     
                      (3)\break
                      In preparation\break   
                       (2)\break
                    In preparation\break
                     \vspace{27pt}\break
                      (1)\break
                      In preparation\break }

  \end{mdframed}

  \end{leftcolumn}
 \begin{rightcolumn}
 \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=10cm, linecolor=red]

  \lipsum{1}


 \end{mdframed}

 \end{rightcolumn}
 \end{paracol}    

 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Weclome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Coud you also clarify what you mean by "there is always some indent"?  Do you mean that the text is not flush against the red frame?  Perhaps a picture/illustration of what's going wrong will help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. A new environment `myparacol` is defined and used, inside it `parindent` is set to 0.

```
\newenvironment{myparacol}[2][]{%
\begin{paracol}{#2}[#1]\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}{%
\end{paracol}}
```

to be used `\begin{myparacol}{2}...\end{myparacol}`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\labelaxes{Remember to include your label}
 \usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{myparacol}[2][]{%
\begin{paracol}{#2}[#1]\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}{%
\end{paracol}}

 \begin{document}

 \columnratio{.3}
 \begin{myparacol}{2}
 \begin{leftcolumn}
 \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=3cm, linecolor=red]

 \raggedleft\textit{(15)\break
                    In preparation\break
                     \vspace{2pt}\break
                      (14)\break
                      In preparation\break
                      \vspace{0pt}\break
                      (13)\break
                      In preparation\break  
                     \vspace{12pt}\break
                      (12)\break
                      In preparation\break
                    \vspace{13pt}\break                         
                      (11)\break
                    In preparation\break
                    \vspace{13pt}\break  
                      (10)\break
                      In preparation\break
                      \vspace{2pt}\break  
                      (9)\break
                      In preparation\break
                    \vspace{-.5pt}\break                            
                      (8)\break
                      In preparation\break
                      \vspace{13pt}\break     
                      (7)\break
                      In preparation\break 
                       \vspace{28pt}\break     
                      (6)\break
                      In preparation\break 
                      \vspace{25pt}\break     
                      (5)\break
                      In preparation\break 
                      \vspace{30pt}\break     
                      (4)\break
                      In preparation\break 
                      \vspace{12pt}\break     
                      (3)\break
                      In preparation\break   
                       (2)\break
                    In preparation\break
                     \vspace{27pt}\break
                      (1)\break
                      In preparation\break }

  \end{mdframed}

  \end{leftcolumn}
 \begin{rightcolumn}
 \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=10cm, linecolor=red]

  \lipsum{1}


 \end{mdframed}

 \end{rightcolumn}
 \end{myparacol}    

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or by use of `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{paracol}
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tikz}    
\def\labelaxes{Remember to include your label}    
    \usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

    \usepackage{etoolbox}% <--- added
\AtBeginEnvironment{paracol}{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}<--- added

\begin{document}
\columnratio{.3}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
.... 
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```